# Добавить в выпадающее меню еще списков но на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите, добавить в выпадающее меню еще списки но через javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/saneq11/ouk587p5/1/

```
<select id="month" width="10">
<option value="Январь">Январь</option> 
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: `$("#month").append("<option value="Февраль">Февраль</option>");`

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML + 
    "<option value='Февраль'>Февраль</option>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const months = ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Декабрь'];
var select = document.getElementById('month');
function appendMonth(element) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = element;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
months.forEach(appendMonth);
```

```html
<select id="month" width="10">
</select>
```